# Delete SharedObject preferences

Tags: actionscript-3, air, blackberry-playbook, shared-objects

I've developed an ActionScript 3.0 for Adobe Air application (it will run on Blackberry Playbook).

This app has some bugs and I've made an update.

When user install the new version I want to delete previous user data.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a property in the shared object to represent your version number, and when checking the data object, if the property is not found or is from an earlier version you know to delete the data object and create a new one.